# Load specific WooCommerce template within theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom page template within my theme, I'm trying to display just the product summary on this page.

So that when this page template is loaded, it loads with the products summary and nothing else.

So far I'm loading the whole product single template and using css to hide the other elements;

```
load_template(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php');
```

This isn't ideal as you load the other elements, however, it seems to call its own `footer.php`, therefore my footer doesn't load.

I do not wish to override WooCommerce templates for this!

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on what you are trying to do? link to a page would also be helpful so we could see what it is your are attempting.

Comment: Not certain what you're after, as Mark says. But `<?= wc_get_product()->get_description(); ?>` would get the description (if that's what you mean by summary) of the current product.

Comment: you can simply add hook to your theme file and wordpress will automatically add the summary. `do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary')`.